# Android Tesseract OCR on Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ocr, tesseract

For a while I have been trying to include teseract in my android app on Android Studio (using [this](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) tutorial). Since it did not work after many trys (missing allheaders.h) I contacted the creators (blog Gautam Gupta and  OCR Robert Theis)they told me to try it on eclipse. Since I am not very found of Eclipse (having various problems) I am wondering, if somebody used Android Studio to make an OCR with tess-two. If so can you maybe write a short instruction?

I am running Mac OS X, if it helps.
Eclipse can't compile its own Hello World Android App (already looked for solutions but didn't work for me), tess-two library shows no problems. I will try and update Eclipse but I still prefer Android Studio (already built a few projects there).

Comment: i am having the same problem . i will surely get help from your answer. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found a good answer myself:
[tesseract on Android Studio](https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq/tesseract-with-andoird-and-gradle)