# Can't do OCR with tess-two on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ocr, tess-two

everyone. I'm trying to include tess-two OCR library to an Android project but some issues occurred.

**[What I'm trying to do]**

Do OCR with tess-two ([tess-two github link](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)) on Android Studio.
(I'd like to develop some OCR apps)

**[Where I'm stuck]**

The app is forced to be terminated when run from Android Studio

**[What I did]**

1. Downloaded tess-two
2. built it

> ```
> ndk-build
> android update project --path C:\...\tess-two  
> ant release
> ```

3. Made a new project "test" on Android Studio (API 16, Blank Activity)
4. Put classes.jar to test\app\libs
5. Added classes.jar as a library to app
6. Put directories with .so files (armeabi-v7a, mips, x86) to test\app\src\main\jniLibs
7. Put the following code in MainActivity.java

> ```
> import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;
>
> public void testOCR(){
>     String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
>     Bitmap bitmap = null;
>     ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
>
>     // Read an image
>     File file = new File("storage/sdcard1/tess-two/ocr_sample.jpg");
>     if (file.exists()) {
>         bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
>         bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
>         img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
>     }else{
>         Log.d("tess-two","File not found.");
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Init modules
>     TessBaseAPI tessOCRAPI = new TessBaseAPI();
>     tessOCRAPI.init(storagePath+"/tess-two/", "eng");
>
>     // Set Image
>     tessOCRAPI.setImage(bitmap);
>     String recognizedText = tessOCRAPI.getUTF8Text();
>     Log.d("tess-two",recognizedText);
>
>     // Close OCR API
>     tessOCRAPI.end();
>
> }
> ```

8. Ran the app on a smartphone.

Then, the app halted. I debugged it and the program seemed to halt at `TessBaseAPI tessOCRAPI = new TessBaseAPI();`. While debugging, the sentence below appeared at the debug windows.

`com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller`

Rebuilding and cleaning the project and searching on google didn't give any good results.

Could anyone suggest a way to solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

**[My environment]**

- Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit
- Android studio 1.3
- Xperia SO-04F

**[Reference]**

- [Android Tesseract OCR on Android Studio [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136882/android-tesseract-ocr-on-android-studio)
- [Including *.so libraries Android Studio tess-two (tesseract)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759959/including-so-libraries-android-studio-tess-two-tesseract)